# Export List of Pandas Dataframe to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xml

Just start learning python recently. Trying to export information from multiple XML files under the same directory, and output the datafram to excel in the code shown below:

```
with open(file_path, "rb"):   # read xml files
  tree = ET.parse(file_path)  # parse file paths

  Data=[]
  col_title = []

  for value in tree.findall("VersionID"): #loop thru file_path to find "VersionID"
    Data.append(value.text)
    col_title.append(value.tag)

  df = pd.DataFrame(Data)  # write in DF
  df.columns = col_title  # change column names

  df.to_excel('output.xlsx') # save to excel file
```

the expected result on Excel should be:

```
     Ver     
0   1.01
0   1.00
0   1.02
...  ...
0   1.09
```

but the actual output is:

```
      Ver
 0    1.09
```

If I were to `print(df)`, it shows:

```
      Ver
 0   1.01
      ver
 0   1.00
      ver
 0   1.02
      ver
 ...  ...
      ver
 0   1.09
```

`print(Data)` will display as follows:

```
['1.01']
['1.00']
['1.02']
...
['1.09']
```

sample XML are in the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sections>
...
<VersionID>1.0.1</VersionID>
  <Date>20211029234567</Date>
  ...
...
</Sections>
```

I wonder whether it is something wrong with the data type, data index, or the loop function.

Comment: Is col_title just `[ver]` or is it a list the same length as Data?

Comment: Not sure if I totally understand you. When I tried print(len(col_title)) or print(len(Data)), they are both printing the same numbers of "1" in column. If print(col_title), it will show ['Ver'] repeatedly in column

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the XML file and the output of `print(Data)`?

Comment: Just updated the post, you should be able to see them now

Comment: `col_title.append(value.tag)` should run only once.. right?

Comment: Try:
`
Data.append(value.text[0])
`
and 
`
df.columns = ["Ver"]
`

Comment: @p._phidot_ commenting `col_title.append(value.tag)` will only replace `Ver` with `0` from the output on `print(df)`.

Comment: may I know which library to import to run `ET.parse`

Comment: @p._phidot_ `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` is the library I used here

Comment: @snag9677 `Data.append(value.text[0])` will give me first char of the Version ID, which is `["1"]`. `df.columns = ["Ver"]` will give me an error `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error in your code. Im using XML
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sections>

    <VersionID>1.0.1</VersionID>
    <Date>20211029234567</Date>

    <VersionID>1.0.2</VersionID>
    <Date>123412</Date>
    
</Sections>`
with the same code as yours (except the df.columns).
`print(Data)` gives me 
`['1.0.1', '1.0.2']`

Comment: the [sample code](https://medium.com/@robertopreste/from-xml-to-pandas-dataframes-9292980b1c1c) shares a different way to use `et.parse()` I'm unfamiliar to xml2df task in python, just hope that the info helps. /(-_-)

Comment: @snag9677 Yes! you were right about the error. I was using transpose of `df` instead. That's why it failed. However, the Excel output is still the same if you tried importing version ID from multiple XML files (not just one XML file). I wonder if the issue is related to the data index.

Comment: @p._phidot_ no problem. thanks for sharing your ideas :)

Comment: @snag9677 Before the `with` function, I have this for loop to read the file path using pathlib library.
`data_folder = Path("xxx/file location")` `for file in listdir(data_folder):` `file_path = data_folder / file`

Comment: @yl129 The problem is that you're re-defining data in every iteration of the for loop so the previous data is overwritten. Put `Data = []` before the loop.